# Time series forecasting with exogenous variables using LSTM/RNN

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to do time series forecasting of a continuous variable(Y1) on the basis of continuous variables(Y1,Y2,Y3) and categorical variables(Y4,Y5). Is there some way to do it using LSTM/RNN?

Comment: You're looking for multivariate times series with exogenous - there's a VAR for that statistically, as well as RNNs like LSTM and seq2seq

Comment: I'm right now revisiting this because I find myself searching for the same thing. -- My LSTM is not doing a great job when most of the columns follow one (gaussian normal) pattern but a couple follow a different (also gaus.) pattern. It seems to do admirably with the larger set (of what would be exog data in VARIMAX), but quite poorly with the endog columns

Comment: I guess the same issue is discussed here: [StackExchange: Adding Features To Time Series Model LSTM](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17099/adding-features-to-time-series-model-lstm)